# Vue 2 -> Vue 3 | There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

I am currently updating an old repository. One of the major upgrades is the switch from vue 2 to vue 3. After fixing all other errors and warnings I am left with these two and I don't have any idea how to fix them.

```
WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings                                                                                                                                                    10:39:23

 warning  in data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27 viewBox=%270 0 1 1%27%3E%3Cpath style=%27fill:%23FFF%27 d=%27M 0.04038059,0.6267767 0.14644661,0.52071068 0.42928932,0.80355339 0.3232233,0.90961941 z M 0.21715729,0.80355339 0.85355339,0.16715729 0.95961941,0.2732233 0.3232233,0.90961941 z%27%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E

There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* asset/inline|data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27 viewBox=%270 0 1 1%27%3E%3Cpath style=%27fill:%23FFF%27 d=%27M 0.04038059,0.6267767 0.14644661,0.52071068 0.42928932,0.80355339 0.3232233,0.90961941 z M 0.21715729,0.80355339 0.85355339,0.16715729 0.95961941,0.2732233 0.3232233,0.90961941 z%27%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[1]!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\stylePostLoader.js!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[2]!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[3]!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!C:\dev\secdem\control\src\App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss
* asset/inline|data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27 viewBox=%270 0 1 1%27%3E%3Cpath style=%27fill:%23fff%27 d=%27M 0.04038059,0.6267767 0.14644661,0.52071068 0.42928932,0.80355339 0.3232233,0.90961941 z M 0.21715729,0.80355339 0.85355339,0.16715729 0.95961941,0.2732233 0.3232233,0.90961941 z%27%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-14.use[1]!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-14.use[2]!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\buefy\dist\buefy.css

 warning  in data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27 viewBox=%270 0 1 1%27%3E%3Crect style=%27fill:%23FFF%27 width=%270.7%27 height=%270.2%27 x=%27.15%27 y=%27.4%27%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/svg%3E

There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* asset/inline|data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27 viewBox=%270 0 1 1%27%3E%3Crect style=%27fill:%23FFF%27 width=%270.7%27 height=%270.2%27 x=%27.15%27 y=%27.4%27%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/svg%3E
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[1]!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\stylePostLoader.js!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[2]!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[3]!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!C:\dev\secdem\control\src\App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss
* asset/inline|data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27 viewBox=%270 0 1 1%27%3E%3Crect style=%27fill:%23fff%27 width=%270.7%27 height=%270.2%27 x=%27.15%27 y=%27.4%27%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/svg%3E
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-14.use[1]!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-14.use[2]!C:\dev\secdem\control\node_modules\buefy\dist\buefy.css
```

From what I can tell by the warning the only casing difference is the fff and FFF in `style=%27fill:%23fff%27` vs `style=%27fill:%23FFF%27`.
However, when trying to search for either of these two in my entire project folder I get no results.

As suggested by similar questions, I also searched for wrong casing in my import statements and paths, but all seems to be correct there.

Not sure if it could be related to this issue, but I used an inofficial fork of buefy that is compatible with vue 3: https://github.com/kikuomax/buefy

So I am not sure what exactly the problem is or how I could fix it.

Comment: The problem is with SVG, that fff/FFF thing shouldn't occur under normal circumstances. It's on project level, it's specific to your setup or the libs in use, not Vue 2 or 3. If Bulma doesn't use SVG then it's likely irrelevant too. The question cannot be answered in its current form, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Alright, thank you. Yes, there is one SVG file in my project that is used for a font. It just seems odd to me that there is something wrong with it because that error never occurred before. I will try a different font and see if that fixes the error.